# Getting TikZ to work on Elementary OS (Ubuntu)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, ubuntu

I'm running Elementary OS (which is a fork of Ubuntu 12.04), and am having troubles getting a LaTeX installation to work.

Code that worked on my old installation on Windows, doesn't appear to work here.

In particular the below code causes an undefined control sequence error:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (.4,1.5);
    \coordinate (C) at (1.5,0);

    \draw (A) node [left]{$A$} -- (C) node[right]{$C$}node[midway,below]{$b$} -- (B) node[above]{$B$}node[midway,right]{$a$} -- cycle node[midway,left]{$c$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Commenting out the `\draw` gets rid of the error. I attempted to use the command in other variations, which worked fine, however the `cycle` keyword caused the error.

The error is as below:

```
[3] [4] [5]
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@node@transformations ...@anchor \tikz@timer 
                                              \fi \tikz@transform 
l.461 }
```

I've installed the `texlive-full` package (and have even attempted to install `pgf` with seemingly no difference) and am attempting to compile using `pdflatex filename.tex`.

If you need any more information, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is likely to have an extremely outdated version of `tikz`, but you can check by adding `\listfiles` to your document and looking at the `.log`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, @jon. You appear to be right. I'm running v2.10 released on 2010/10/13. Do you know a ppa I can use to get a newer version?

Comment: Sorry, no. I think you're better off installing the `.tds.zip` from its [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).  They are designed for easy install: just unzip at the root of your `texmf` tree.

Comment: I'm gonna sound dumb now, but what exactly is a `texmf` tree? I've never had to install things manually before.

Comment: Or install Vanilla TeX Live directly from TUG. For many Linux users the best choice.

Comment: It's the directory "tree" containing (in theory) all your TeX and MetaFont files. There are three trees: main, local, and personal. The root of each can be found with these commands: `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFMAIN`, `kpsewhich --var-value TEXLOCAL`, and `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`. Home is searched before local, and local before main. If you don'tt want to risk borking your current install, run the last command, which will likely point to `/home/<user>/texmf`; create the directory if needed, then `cd` to that directory, and unzip.  If things go screwy delete that folder.

Comment: But the better solution really is what @Johannes_B suggested.  (More time invested now, but more time saved in the long run.)

Comment: I'll try Jonhannes' suggestion then, thank you. I'll report back whenever I've installed all 3000 packages again.

Comment: Actually: TeX Live 2015 is due out in about 2 weeks. You might want to wait until then to do the install; otherwise, you'll need to do it again if you want to benefit from having a current install.  My suggestion might be "better" for now, depending on how much you like installing 3000 packages....

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it. I followed the instruction at https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @jon I wouldn't mind updating again later, but I need a working installation right about now.

Comment: Well, the "quick" fix is to install the .tds.zip. Not sure what you have now if you've also installed from TUG.  (The command `which latex` might be of help here, if you are unsure also.)

Comment: latex is in /usr/bin/latex, like I expected. I'll try the quick fix.